# Kotlin class basics

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to adapt some production Java to Kotlin but I have to take it down a notch since apparently I can't figure out even the basics.

Java:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person("me");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```

How would you do that or similar in Kotlin? Only this perhaps:

```
// Person.kt
open class Person(var name: String)

$ kotlinc Person.kt && javap -p Person.class
Compiled from "Person.kt"
public class Person {
  private java.lang.String name;
  public final java.lang.String getName();
  public final void setName(java.lang.String);
  public Person(java.lang.String);
}
```

Neat, so let's put all that auto-generated stuff to use:

```
open class Person(var name: String)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person("me")
    println(p.getName())
}

$ kotlinc Person.kt 
Person.kt:4:15: error: unresolved reference: getName
    println(p.getName())
              ^
```

What's the problem? `p.name` works, but I'm guessing that's because it's all in the same file. Heck, I can't even test if that's true:

```
// PersonDemo.kt in same dir as Person.kt
object PersonDemo {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val p = Person("me")
    }
}

$ kotlinc PersonDemo.kt || (kotlinc Person.kt && kotlinc PersonDemo.kt)
PersonDemo.kt:3:17: error: unresolved reference: Person
        var p = Person("me")
                ^
PersonDemo.kt:3:17: error: unresolved reference: Person
        var p = Person("me")
                ^
```

Import maybe? No, not that either.

Scouring [classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) documentation is no use, so, can someone tell me how this basic stuff is done?

Answer (score 2):

Just write the below code in `Person` class and run it.

```
// Person class in Kotlin
class Person(name:String) {
    val name:String
    // initializing name variable
    init {
        this.name = name
    }
    // main method converts to this in Kotlin
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args:Array<String>) {
            val p = Person("me")
            println(p.name)
        }
    }
}
```

We can remove the initialization process here as we can directly access the name variable from the primary constructor. So, the above Kotlin code can be optimized to:

```
class Person(val name: String) {

    // main method converts to this in Kotlin
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args:Array<String>) {
            val p = Person("me")
            println(p.name)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't use `getName` or use `Person` from a different file?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Person class will be accessible as it's a public class. Just create an instance of that with the parameters. Then access it by instance.name

Comment: Sure, but how? I already showed how I tried creating a `Person` instance and failed.

Comment: Why separate the initialization from the definition?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What do you mean? Do you find it unusual to want to use classes defined outside of your own project?

Comment: I just didn't know why there was an additional `(name: String)`, a `val name: String` and an `init { this.name = name}` when you can replace that completely with `(val name: String)` and it does the same thing (and as it was added in an edit 11 hours ago)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `getName` because Kotlin has a bit different approach with class attributes compared to Java, in Java it is standard to have private attribute with **getter** and **setter** methods used for accessing, in Kotlin its standard to have properties.

There are 2 kinds of properties:

1. Those declared with `var` which makes them mutable, and their value can be changed, this properties have two methods associated with them `set` and `get`
2. Those declared with `val` which makes them immutable, so their value can't be changed, as they can't be changed they only have `get` method associated with them.

Above mentioned `get` and `set` methods don't need to be specified.

So following Kotlin class:

```
open class Person(var name: String,val id: Int)
```

is equivalent to following Java class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private final int id;

    public Person(String name, int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Note that `id` is **val** so it only has **getter**.

Each property is by default `public` in Kotlin, and they can be either declared inside constructor or inside class same as you would do in Java. Last mentioned method of declaration is used when we want to change default behavior of `get` and/or `set` associated with that property.

Now in other to explain this better let me give you an example, so lets imagine that we have class person that we used above, but we need to prefix each name with "Name: ".

In Java we would rewrite above mentioned **getter** in following way:

```
public String getName() {
    return "Name: " + name;
}
```

In other to get same thing in Kotlin we need to write something like this:

```
open class Person(name: String,val id: Int){
    var name: String = name
        get() = "Name: $field"
}
```

Note that we don't use `name` inside `get`, but instead we use `field` to refer to our property, also its important to see that we didn't write `val` or `var` for name inside constructor, this means that it will be just regular parameter.

There are a lot more neat tricks with properties, like having `var` but making `set` private so you can change value only inside that class, late-initialized properties and much more.

As final part of my answer, lets see how one would use our class, written in **KOTLIN**.

If we use that class from Kotlin code:

```
val person = Person("KotlinPerson", 123)
person.name = "John"
val personName = person.name
val personId = person.id
```

Using same class but inside Java:

```
Person person = new Person("JavaPersonFromKotlinClass", 123);
person.setName("John");
String personName = person.getName();
int personId = person.getId();
```

For the end I will just add that opposite works as well, you can make Person.java from above code, and code in Kotlin will still work completely fine, only difference is that when using Java code you get `String?` because Java doesn't guarantee that some value isn't null.

Comment: In addition to this answer: even for the original Java class, when using it from Kotlin you can and should use `person.name` instead of `person.getName()`.

Comment: @FilipRistic Thanks for the thorough explanation. I'm still confused about calling `getName` or `name`. I suppose that even though the `javap` output says there's a `getName` method, for Kotlin intents and purposes there isn't, different namespace scheme or something like that.

Comment: As my answer is pretty long and there is already explanation, I will give you 2 links which should help you, but yes you are correct, when you have Kotlin class, from Kotlin perspective it has only `name`, from java perspective it has `getName` and `setName`.

Comment: Here are links that explain this: [java from kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html), [kotlin from java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html)

Answer (score 0):

> How would you do that or similar in Kotlin?

```
class Person(val name: String) {
     companion object {
          @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
               val p = Person("me") 
               System.out.println(p.name);
          } 
     }
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation on how this answer works

Comment: Hmm I just converted the class by hand to match the same code as what was written in Java. Which part needs explanation?